# ngrx/store selector returns [object Object]

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

I am trying to use the ngrx/store in my project which a flow of 4 forms and the last page is the summary to display the form details that we have been added.

I am not able to select the data from the store on the last page.

e.g: `this.appStartState = this.store.select('priceOfHouseApartment');`

returns `[object Object]`

Here is the URL of the project that I am working on:
https://github.com/kunalp16/newAngularWithRedux

Answer (score 0):

If you receive `[object Object]` you can use the `json` pipe to display the data like this in the HTML template:

```
<div>{{ data | json }}</div>
```

If you want a specific item of the object you could do something like this:

```
<div>{{ data.yourKey }}</div>
```

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you're looking for. Please tell me if this helped :)